Error in autotrain stable diffusion (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'autotrain')
I am using python 3.11 and cuda 12.1. I am trying to train model on my local machine. but after install it is giving error..
!pip install -U autotrain-advanced

!autotrain setup --update-torch

I have done above command but when I try the following
autotrain dreambooth --model stabilityai/stable-diffusion-xl-base-1.0 --image-path ayaz/ --prompt "photo of ayaz1 person" --resolution 1024 --batch-size 1 --num-steps 100 --gradient-accumulation 4 --lr 1e-4 --project-name my-autotrain-project

it shows the following error
autotrain dreambooth --model stabilityai/stable-diffusion-xl-base-1.0 --image-path ayaz/ --prompt "photo of ayaz1 person" --resolution 1024 --batch-size 1 --num-steps 100 --gradient-accumulation 4 --lr 1e-4 --project-name my-autotrain-project
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
File "C:\Ayaz\My_Projects\Prj_general\venv_general\Scripts\autotrain.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
File "C:\Ayaz\My_Projects\Prj_general\venv_general\Lib\site-packages\autotrain\cli\autotrain.py", line 67, in main
command = args.func(args)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Ayaz\My_Projects\Prj_general\venv_general\Lib\site-packages\autotrain\cli\run_dreambooth.py", line 21, in run_dreambooth_command_factory
return RunAutoTrainDreamboothCommand(args)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Ayaz\My_Projects\Prj_general\venv_general\Lib\site-packages\autotrain\cli\run_dreambooth.py", line 365, in __init__
raise ValueError("❌ Please specify a valid image directory")
ValueError: ❌ Please specify a valid image directory

(venv_general) C:\Ayaz\My_Projects\Prj_general\Test>
(venv_general) C:\Ayaz\My_Projects\Prj_general\Test>cd " C:\Ayaz\My_Projects\Prj_general"
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
(venv_general) C:\Ayaz\My_Projects\Prj_general\Test> cd "C:\Ayaz\My_Projects\Prj_general"
(venv_general) C:\Ayaz\My_Projects\Prj_general>autotrain dreambooth --model stabilityai/stable-diffusion-xl-base-1.0 --image-path ayaz/ --prompt "photo of ayaz1 person" --resolution 1024 --batch-size 1 --num-steps 100 --gradient-accumulation 4 --lr 1e-4 --project-name my-autotrain-project
INFO     | 2024-08-09 10:20:43 | autotrain.cli.run_dreambooth:run:388 - Running DreamBooth Training
WARNING  | 2024-08-09 10:20:43 | autotrain.trainers.common:__init__:180 - Parameters supplied but not used: inference, log, version, deploy, train_split, valid_split, func, train, data_path, config, backend
INFO     | 2024-08-09 10:20:43 | autotrain.preprocessor.dreambooth:_save_concept_images:67 - Saving concept images
INFO     | 2024-08-09 10:20:43 | autotrain.preprocessor.dreambooth:_save_concept_images:68 - ayaz/20160426_182736.jpg
INFO     | 2024-08-09 10:20:43 | autotrain.preprocessor.dreambooth:_save_concept_images:67 - Saving concept images
INFO     | 2024-08-09 10:20:43 | autotrain.preprocessor.dreambooth:_save_concept_images:68 - ayaz/20160912_071125.jpg
INFO     | 2024-08-09 10:20:43 | autotrain.preprocessor.dreambooth:_save_concept_images:67 - Saving concept images
INFO     | 2024-08-09 10:20:43 | autotrain.preprocessor.dreambooth:_save_concept_images:68 - ayaz/20160920_133005(0).jpg
INFO     | 2024-08-09 10:20:43 | autotrain.preprocessor.dreambooth:_save_concept_images:67 - Saving concept images
INFO     | 2024-08-09 10:20:43 | autotrain.preprocessor.dreambooth:_save_concept_images:68 - ayaz/20160920_133014.jpg
INFO     | 2024-08-09 10:20:43 | autotrain.preprocessor.dreambooth:_save_concept_images:67 - Saving concept images
INFO     | 2024-08-09 10:20:43 | autotrain.preprocessor.dreambooth:_save_concept_images:68 - ayaz/20161017_110932.jpg
INFO     | 2024-08-09 10:20:43 | autotrain.preprocessor.dreambooth:_save_concept_images:67 - Saving concept images
INFO     | 2024-08-09 10:20:43 | autotrain.preprocessor.dreambooth:_save_concept_images:68 - ayaz/20161017_113647.jpg
INFO     | 2024-08-09 10:20:43 | autotrain.preprocessor.dreambooth:_save_concept_images:67 - Saving concept images
INFO     | 2024-08-09 10:20:43 | autotrain.preprocessor.dreambooth:_save_concept_images:68 - ayaz/20161017_141325.jpg
INFO     | 2024-08-09 10:20:43 | autotrain.preprocessor.dreambooth:_save_concept_images:67 - Saving concept images
INFO     | 2024-08-09 10:20:43 | autotrain.preprocessor.dreambooth:_save_concept_images:68 - ayaz/20161019_102543.jpg
INFO     | 2024-08-09 10:20:43 | autotrain.preprocessor.dreambooth:_save_concept_images:67 - Saving concept images
INFO     | 2024-08-09 10:20:43 | autotrain.preprocessor.dreambooth:_save_concept_images:68 - ayaz/20161019_102546.jpg
INFO     | 2024-08-09 10:20:43 | autotrain.backends.local:create:8 - Starting local training...
INFO     | 2024-08-09 10:20:43 | autotrain.commands:launch_command:478 - ['python', '-m', 'autotrain.trainers.dreambooth', '--training_config', 'my-autotrain-project\\training_params.json']
INFO     | 2024-08-09 10:20:43 | autotrain.commands:launch_command:479 - {'model': 'stabilityai/stable-diffusion-xl-base-1.0', 'vae_model': None, 'revision': None, 'tokenizer': None, 'image_path': 'my-autotrain-project/autotrain-data', 'class_image_path': None, 'prompt': 'photo of ayaz1 person', 'class_prompt': None, 'num_class_images': 100, 'class_labels_
conditioning': None, 'prior_preservation': False, 'prior_loss_weight': 1.0, 'project_name': 'my-autotrain-project', 'seed': 42, 'resolution': 1024, 'center_crop': False, 'train_te
xt_encoder': False, 'batch_size': 1, 'sample_batch_size': 4, 'epochs': 1, 'num_steps': 100, 'checkpointing_steps': 100000, 'resume_from_checkpoint': None, 'gradient_accumulation':
4, 'disable_gradient_checkpointing': False, 'lr': 0.0001, 'scale_lr': False, 'scheduler': 'constant', 'warmup_steps': 0, 'num_cycles': 1, 'lr_power': 1.0, 'dataloader_num_workers
': 0, 'use_8bit_adam': False, 'adam_beta1': 0.9, 'adam_beta2': 0.999, 'adam_weight_decay': 0.01, 'adam_epsilon': 1e-08, 'max_grad_norm': 1.0, 'allow_tf32': False, 'prior_generatio
n_precision': None, 'local_rank': -1, 'xformers': False, 'pre_compute_text_embeddings': False, 'tokenizer_max_length': None, 'text_encoder_use_attention_mask': False, 'rank': 4, '
xl': True, 'mixed_precision': 'none', 'token': None, 'push_to_hub': False, 'username': None, 'validation_prompt': None, 'num_validation_images': 4, 'validation_epochs': 50, 'checkpoints_total_limit': None, 'validation_images': None, 'logging': False}
C:\Users\Gaming PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe: Error while finding module specification for 'autotrain.trainers.dreambooth' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'autotrain')

I have tried on different python version.
